# Omnipotent Suitcase Story

Tags: story-identification, stanislaw-lem

Please help me identify where this story is from, I believe it was written by Stanislaw Lem and is a part of a Ijon Tichy book, however I can not figure out which one.

The plot, from what I remember: 
Ijon Tichy finds a suitcase in a desert and decides to kick it. The suitcase tells Ijon not to do that again, for it is the most perfect being in the universe. Ijon asks why it looks like a suitcase, to which the being responds by saying it doesn't care how it looks, as it is perfect anyway. After some more questions Ijon kicks the suitcase again and gets sent to the opposite side of the galaxy.

Comment: I thought I had all the Ijon Tichy books but I don't recognise this. There is a story where he kicks a robot that has been built to answer all questions (the robot claims 2 + 2 = 7) and the robot gets violent in response. Is it possible you've mixed up this with another story.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, purchase the book in one of _those_ shops?

Comment: It bears some resemblance to when Rincewind acquires the Luggage in The Light Fantastic.

Comment: @JohnRennie That's not an Ijon Tichy story, that's a Trurl story. Trurl built the robot. And I suspect that OP might be a slightly misremembered version of a Trurl story too.